# delete heroku apps in one time with link

Tags: javascript, html, heroku

I was using this script to delete my apps on Heroku but now I think they changed their url. Can any one here can help me and give me the link?

PS: lol is the textarea where I put the name of the apps

```
function go2() { 
   strr = document.getElementById("lol").value ; 
   array = strr.split("\n"); 

   for(i = 1; i< array.length ; i=i+2) { 
      document.getElementById("usa").innerHTML += 'https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/'+array[i]+'/settings?del=true<br>'; 
      strr = document.getElementById("lol2").value +='https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/'+array[i]+'/settings?del=true\n'; 
   } 
   strr2 = document.getElementById("lol2").value ; 
   array2 = strr2.split("\n"); 
   document.getElementById("usa").innerHTML += '<h2 style="color:red">'+array2.length+'</h2>' 
}
```

Comment: Did you delete your apps by GET reuqest back then from another domain?

Answer (score 0):

Under your project settings page on heroku (https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/APP_NAME/settings), you can observe that network request on your browser's developer tools window:
And if you refresh the page when this windows is open then you can see the get request made as below;

For example on network section there is a domain tab and below GET requests for my application;

```
Request URL: https://api.heroku.com/apps/a7b4f553-d7cd-4d6f-9395-d982da59b706/domains
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 52.44.154.88:443
Referrer Policy: origin
```

So you can see your application unique number on request URL. In this case my application ID is a7b4f553-d7cd-4d6f-9395-d982da59b706.

So after all when you delete the application you can also see that on network windows there made a HTTP DELETE request with a title of your application ID.

```
Request URL: https://api.heroku.com/apps/a7b4f553-d7cd-4d6f-9395-d982da59b706
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 52.44.154.88:443
Referrer Policy: origin
```

So It seems that you can not delete your heroku application just by get request. You need to make a delete request to server with your application ID.